# Getting the visible items inside Gridview(Windows store)

Tags: c#, gridview, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I am developing a Windows Store App and kind of new to C# and Windows framework. I have a gridview and the databinding is being done using GridView.ItemTemplate and DataTemplate. The Gridview may have number of items at any point of time. And i have to only get the items which are currently visible to the user.

Please suggest the right approach to achieve this. Some CODE SNIPPETS will be really helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to get only items who is visible for user? It's really strange with a normal implementation and it's not possible. If you really need this, you need to see incremental implementation. But say us more aobut your application and we can find a solution i think.

Comment: Unfortunately, we're not here to do your work for you. On top of that, your request has come off as quite demanding, which is likely why you're getting downvotes. On this site, you need to show that you have done at least the most basic research. MSFT has provided quite a few example applications which describe practically the exact scenario here with some minor implementation details left to you. If you get a bit further along in the process and have a specific question about a specific instance, then feel free to return and ask about that. Good luck on your journey.

Comment: @Nate no offence meant mate.I apologize if i came across as demanding.

Comment: @Nate no offence meant mate.I apologize if i came across as demanding.@MatDev8 Thanks.I'll explain it in brief. I've a Gridview  inside the datatemplate of which i have a grid which is getting bound to a viewmodel.That grid is repeated multiple times depending on the data.I thought if i find out the coordinates of each grid item i can find the items which are visible using the viewport coordinates. But if i iterate through the items of the grid say foreach(var item in _grdVw)i'll gt the viewmodel instances not the items inside the GrdVw.Plz  suggst a better apprch if known.

Comment: No worries at all, I was just trying to explain the community's response. When you say "I'll get the viewmodel instances, not the items inside the GridView", do you mean that you are trying to get the `UIElement`s (i.e. `GridViewItem`s)? If so, why do you need that to happen?

Comment: @Nate , i think i found the answer. Please refer the code below, Yes i needed to get the items inside the gridview which were infact multiple grids bound to different data and check if each such grid falls into the view able area.

Answer (score 0):

```
         //I think i found the answer
         //GridList is the list of items inside the GridView    
     //grv is the gridView instance
     //sv is the scrollview
        Rect bounds = Window.Current.Bounds;                        
        double height = bounds.Height;
        double width = bounds.Width;
        var ttf = sv.TransformToVisual(Window.Current.Content);
        Windows.Foundation.Point screenCoordsSv = ttf.TransformPoint(new Windows.Foundation.Point(0, 0));

        foreach (Grid grv in GridList)
        {                
            double gridWidth = grv.Width;


            var ttv = grv.TransformToVisual(Window.Current.Content);
            Windows.Foundation.Point screenCoords = ttv.TransformPoint(new Windows.Foundation.Point(0, 0));

            if ((screenCoords.X >= -(gridWidth + 10)) && (screenCoords.X < width))
            {                    
               //item falls inside the visible area
            }
        }
```